# 2 Dimensional Object Wrapper Java

Tags: java

I was wondering which approach to take to create a 2-Dimensional "Array-like" (or array) of Generics.

1. Create a list of lists

   ```
   LinkedList<LinkedList<T>> myObject;
   ```
2. Or this method, which is more intuitive but requires the usage of Refecltion to retrieve the type.

   ```
   T[] testArray = c.cast(Array.
           newInstance(c.getComponentType(), dim1, dim2));
   ```

The idea is that i have a class which contains a member variable:

```
public class Board<T>
{
    T[][] array;

    public Board(int vertical_size, int horizontal_size)
    {
        array = new T[vertical_size][horizontal_size]; //which is not allowed because of the way that java implements Generics
    }
}
```

Which one of the two approaches that I listed above should I take.. or is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `T[][]` - you can use an `Object[][]` just as easily (and cast as `T` when needed). This should pose no problem if you only allow `T` instances to populate the array.

In fact, if you [take a look](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java), you will find that an `ArrayList<T>` is backed by an `Object[]` (not a `T[]`) and uses a similar approach:

```
111     private transient Object[] elementData;

...

336     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
337     E elementData(int index) {
338         return (E) elementData[index];
339     }
```

I imagine that this approach will be much more efficient than a list-of-lists if you will not need to resize your board dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an array with type safety, you can simply do the following. Not sure where everyone got the notion you couldn't do it:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class Array2D<T> {
    private T[][] data;

    public Array2D(Class<T> clazz, int width, int height) {
        this.data = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(clazz, width, height);
    }

    public void putValue(int x, int y, T value) {
        data[x][y] = value;
    }

    public T getValue(int x, int y) {
        return data[x][y];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Array2D<String> myStuff = new Array2D<String>(String.class, 10, 10);
        myStuff.putValue(3, 4, "Helloworld!");

        System.out.println(myStuff.getValue(3, 4));
    }
}
```

Output:

Helloworld!

**Edit:**

If you need more performance, consider using a 1D array and treating like an n-dimensional array. This is a known improvement when working with android devices, but only if you are constantly accessing the array.

Additionally, you could force the caller to create the array and completely avoid using reflection. However, unless you are creating these arrays very often it won't make a significant difference, and even less so when the JVM optimizes the call.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class Array2D<T> {
    private T[] data;
    private final int height;
    private final int width;

    public Array2D(Class<T> clazz, int width, int height) {
        // Using 1D array instead of 2D array
        this((T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, width * height), width, height); 
    }

    public Array2D(T[] data, int width, int height) {
        this.data = data;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void putValue(int x, int y, T value) {
        data[x * width + y] = value;
    }

    public T getValue(int x, int y) {
        return data[x * width + y];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Array2D<String> myStuff = new Array2D<String>(String.class, 10, 10);
        myStuff.putValue(3, 4, "Helloworld!");

        System.out.println(myStuff.getValue(3, 4));

        // Force the caller to create the array
        Array2D<String> myOtherStuff = new Array2D<String>(new String[5 * 10], 5, 10);
        myOtherStuff.putValue(2, 7, "Goodbyeworld!");

        System.out.println(myOtherStuff.getValue(2, 7));
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you suggest that the usage of Reflection would be better than  making a List of lists?

Comment: Depends on what your purpose is for the collection. If you want something with quick access time because you will be constantly accessing the array (i.e. thousands of times per second) and your okay with fixed size, you can go with the reflection approach. Neither approach is wrong, and if you are using it inside of a class then it really comes down to preference more than anything else. I'll update my answer with another solution that is even faster if performance is critical (it also assumes fixed size).

Answer (score 1):

This is my idea (IF I understood the question):

```
 class TwoDArray<T> {

    List<List<T>> list;

    public TwoDArray(int rows, int columns) {
    list = new ArrayList<List<T>>(rows);

    for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++) { 
        list.add(new ArrayList<T>(columns));
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        list.get(i).add(j, null);
    }

    }

    public T getItem(int x, int y) {
    return list.get(x).get(y);
    }

    public void addItem(int x, int y, T e) {
    list.get(x).set(y, e);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    TwoDArray<String> bdimensional = new TwoDArray<String>(2, 2);
    bdimensional.addItem(1, 1, new String("hello"));
    bdimensional.addItem(0, 1, new String("bye"));  
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        System.out.println( i + " " + j + ": " + bdimensional.getItem(i,j));
    }

    }

}
```

the output is:

```
0 0: null
0 1: bye
1 0: null
1 1: hello
```

I don't why my brain was convinced that `(T) null` with `nCopies` was going to work. 
Please look at [Convenience Implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/convenience.html).

Comment: `nCopies` returns n 'copies' of the *same instance*, which will not work here since a change in one row will effect all the others.

Comment: @arshajii tnx pal, I corrected the implementation. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there is absolutely no way of trying to achieve a 2D array of type `T[][]`.

I think you yourself have answered question with the first type. But another interesting way (if possible) would be: When you know the type `T` will always be a subtype of someother type. If none, there is always `Object`

```
interface SomeInterface{}

public class Board<T extends SomeInterface>
{
    SomeInterface[][] array;

    public Board(int horizontal_size, int vertical_size)
    {
        array = new SomeInterface[vertical_size][horizontal_size]; 
    }
}
```

and then you might use `array` as you would like a 2D array. Though I would still prefer `ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>`

Comment: Note that there's always a known supertype: Object.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good solution, it's  a java limitation.

I prefer `Object[][].`

this is closest to that what you want to do with the 2d-strucure.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways, but since you are wrapping the implementation anyway, you can simply use a single array:

```
public class Board<T>
{
    private final Object[] array;
    private final int horizontal_size;

    public Board(int horizontal_size, int vertical_size)
    {
        array = new Object[vertical_size][horizontal_size];
        this.horizontal_size = horizontal_size;
    }

    // ...

    E get(int x, int y){
        // Check  if not out of bounds
        return (E) array[y * horizontal_size + x];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is very limited when it comes down to the use of Generics. Your best bet would be using a 2D Object array (e.g. Object[][])